# FindStringExact on ComboBox returning incorrect index

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I have two ComboBoxes in a WinForm application that display COM ports detected on the system.  They're both bound to a single array containing strings for each COM port.  The array is populated by a call to `SerialPort.GetPortNames()`.  I created new BindingContexts for the ComboBoxes to avoid the issue with them sharing the same data source causing changes in one to affect the other.

I attempt to select a previously saved value by searching for this value in the ComboBox with `FindStringExact()`.

Whilst running in the debugger, I noticed that the index being returned by `FindStringExact()` was a different index to where that string is in the source array.

For example (taken from the Immediate Window), here is the `DataSource` for the ComboBoxes:

```
comboBoxController1ComPort.DataSource

{string[0x00000003]}
    [0x00000000]: "COM3"
    [0x00000001]: "COM10"
    [0x00000002]: "COM12"
```

I would have thought that searching for COM3 would have returned index 0, COM10 index 1 and COM12 index 2.  However, I get different values:

```
comboBoxController1ComPort.FindStringExact("COM3")
0x00000002

comboBoxController1ComPort.FindStringExact("COM10")
0x00000000

comboBoxController1ComPort.FindStringExact("COM12")
0x00000001

comboBoxController1ComPort.FindStringExact("COM1")
0xffffffff
```

I cannot understand why I'm getting different indexes from `FindStringExact()` to those returned by the `DataSource` property.  Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the items are [sorted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted%28VS.80%29.aspx)...

Comment: Brilliant - thanks for the quick answer.  I hadn't noticed that the ComboBox was displaying a different order to the DataSource, and hadn't even realised I'd previously set the Sorted property to True.